# И тебе(,) и мне

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, повторяющийся-союз, смысловое-единство

`Это статья, причем и тебе(,) и мне.`

`А можно писать и «пепперони»(,) и «пеперони»?`

`Это слово можно писать и с одной Н(,) и с двумя.`

Нужно ли ставить запятушонки таки? Не могу понять, есть тут смысловое единство или нет. В первом вроде как не нужна, а во втором и третьем — не знаю. Как думаете, совы?

Comment: – Угусики! – сказала она, и тотчас перед её носом возникли четыре вращающихся ствола пулемага. – МОИХ СЛОВ не использовать! – предупредила Задора. – Агасики? «Агасики!» – хотела повторить Ева, но вовремя притормозила и только кивнула. Пулемаг из ручек Задоры исчез, и она вновь стала милой девчушкой. (Д. Емец. Сокровище Сивояры.)

Comment: @Sharon Что вы хотели этим сказать?

Comment: Это я про "запятушонки". Это же неологизм Лео,  его слово.   Ну и стиль его копируете.  Куда как лучше придумать что-нибудь свое в оформлении ответов, в речи, в чем-то еще Какой-нибудь фирменный знак качества и стиля.  Агусики?

Comment: @Sharon Не знаю, я часто «заражаюсь» речью от другого.

Comment: Я тоже,  но из книг. (Вот мне "агусики" понравились.)  В комментариях мы более свободны, но ответы лучше оформлять  в своем стиле.

Comment: @Sharon Хорошо, учту.

Comment: @Sharon может это хозяин кота?

Comment: @Буратино Не, просто у меня всегда так: когда вижу новую манеру речи — «заражаюсь» от нее. Хотя это не со всеми.

Comment: Нет тут никакого смыслового единства. Смысловое единство, когда можно заменить другим словом или выражением, в единственном числе: муж и жена - союз, семья. Слово с одной н или с двумя - это смыслово значит слово со сколькими Н? полутора?

Comment: @Максим Ясно, ну что-то вроде риторической мимикрии) или риторической внушаемости) ну зато так можно выучить много новых слов.

Comment: @Буратино  Смешно (про кота)!  И почему вы прогуливаете воскресные семинары и конференции?)  А по поводу смыслового единства  я не согласна. Формулировку Розенталя надо понимать с точи зрения грамматики (значения союза И,,,И при отсутствии запятой).

Comment: @Sharon какие еще воскресные мероприятия?)

Comment: Как это какие! Вчера же воскресенье было, а вас не было)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ

1. В первом предложении возможны **варианты, выбор по контексту**:

(1) *Это статья, причем **и тебе и мнЕ.***

(2) *Это статья, причем **и тебЕ, и мнЕ.***

2. В остальных предложениях **запятая нужна:**

*А можно писать **и «пепперОни», и «пеперОни»?***

*Это слово можно писать **и с однОй Н, и с двумЯ**.*

**Пояснение:** https://orfoschool.ru/page_81831_copy31/